# Simple add local repo to remote repo's main branch (not master)

Tags: git, github

This is driving me up the wall!

This is what I've done:

1. Created a folder with some code (local repo)
2. Created a repo in Github e.g. `my_repo`
3. Issued these commands (and trial and error'ed hella other stuff too):

```sh
git init && \
git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/main && \
git remote add origin https://github.com/my_github/my_repo.git && \
git checkout -b init_branch && \
git add * && \
git commit -m "Initial commit" && \
git push origin init_branch && \
git checkout main && \
git merge init_branch
```

The error I'm seeing:

```
 ! [rejected]        init_branch -> init_branch (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my_github/my_repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

On occasions getting this error (not sure why):

```
error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

What I've tried:

1. Switching the default branch in Github from `main` to `master` and pushing straight to `master` - that worked but want to keep it as `main`.
2. Not creating a new branch and attempting to push straight to `main` - doesn't work.
3. Having `git remote add origin ...` straight after `git init` - doesn't work.
4. Removed the `symbolic-ref` line, added `git config --global init.defaultBranch main` and `git pull origin main`. New error:

```
* branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .gitignore
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I think you need to say what you are trying to do rather than give your solution. I suspect you have got mixed up as to how to use git, but without a description of what you are trying to do you are not going to get a valid suggestion:)

Comment: @johnfo I am trying to "add local repo to remote repo's main branch (not master)" :)

Comment: The "add local repo" bit is nonsensical to me. At one point you talk about repos and the other branches. Apples and Oranges.

Comment: A bit pedantic. Wording may not have been grossly accurate but hey, that's where SO comes in. Got the answer I needed.

Comment: I am glad you did. I still don't understand what you really wanted though. I was not being pedantic:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Make sure you create an *empty* repository on GitHub.  Don't put in that initial commit.  Then you can get rid of most of this stuff: you'll just create your new repository, commit to create `main` (and rename to `main` if necessary), do a `git remote add origin url`, and `git push origin main`.

(You can then, if you wish, use `git remote set-head origin --auto`, although I personally find no value here.)

## Long

OK, first, don't do this at all:

> ```
> git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin/main && \
> ```

It's not inherently *wrong* but it has no value.<sup>1</sup>  It has nothing to do with the errors you're getting, but removing it gets one more step out of the way and removes distractions from your view.

With that said, I *think* your problem stems from a fundamental misunderstanding of Git: of what it does, why, and how.  To fix that, let's take a quick overview of Git repositories.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm of the opinion that the existence of `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` itself has no value to begin with, but even if you disagree, you should be using `git remote` or `git ls-remote` to obtain their symbolic `HEAD` here, rather than hard-coding `main`.  Your remote-tracking names are supposed to reflect their branch names as they exist now, not as you wish they existed.

---

#### Git's [*raison d'être*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre) is the commit, for which there are databases

A Git repository is, in the end, all about *commits*.  To get there, Git has a big database of what it calls *objects*.  There are four kinds of objects: commits, tags (annotated tags), trees, and blobs.  The commits are the ones we (humans) mostly care about; the others just have supporting roles and we can mostly ignore them.

Each object—including the crucial commit objects—has a unique *hash ID*.  This hash ID is how Git *finds* the object.  Git stores the objects in a simple [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), with the hash ID being the key.  So we need the hash ID to retrieve a commit.  But hash IDs are big and ugly, e.g., <sub><sup>[`5a73c6bdc717127c2da99f57bc630c4efd8aed02`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a73c6bdc717127c2da99f57bc630c4efd8aed02)</sup></sub>.  They *need* to be big and ugly because *every commit in the universe* has to have *its own* hash ID.<sup>2</sup>

But this makes them too difficult for humans to use.  There's a solution for that though.  Besides the commit-and-other-objects database, each Git repository also has a *names* database.  Here, the database is still a key-value store, but this time the *keys* are things like *branch and tag names*, and the values are big ugly hash IDs.

Each name maps to exactly *one* hash ID.  That's all we need, in Git, because a *branch* name automatically means "the latest commit on that branch", by storing the hash ID *of* the latest commit on that branch.  (We'll skip over how that leads to all the rest of the commits, at least for now.)

The two databases, then, allow us to:

- supply a name like `master` or `main`;
- have Git turn that into a commit hash ID; and
- have Git use that to retrieve the commit.

The commit itself holds two things: a snapshot of every file, as of the form the file had at the time you (or whoever) made it, and some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  Again, we won't go into any of the details here just yet.  All we need to know right now is this two-database thing.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is technically impossible: eventually, two different commits *will* get the same hash ID.  Fortunately, there are two tools we can use here: (1) we can make the hash ID big and ugly so that the "eventually" does not happen for billions of years; (2) we can avoid introducing two Git repositories to each other if they have what I call [doppelgängers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger): objects that should be different but have the same hash ID.  In service of item 1, Git is in the process of moving to bigger hash IDs today.

---

#### `git init`

Running `git init` in a place (folder / directory) where there is as yet no Git *repository* will *create a new, empty repository*.  This repository has no commits—its object database is essentially empty—and since *names* are required to hold valid *object hash IDs*, with *branch* names being required to hold *commit* hash IDs, the names database is also empty.  There are no commits, so there cannot be any branch names.

Note that running `git init` in a place where there *is* a Git repository is mostly a big and slightly-slow nothing.  Git will say that it "re-initialized" the repository: Git did some housekeeping type items, and checked up on some auxiliary items like templated Git hooks and so on.  But the important parts of the existing repository—the two databases—are completely undisturbed by a `git init`.

With an *empty* repository, though, there are *no commits* and therefore *no branches*.  **And yet, even in an empty repository like this, you're "on" some branch: `git status` will say `on branch master` or `on branch main` or whatever.**  What's going on here?

#### More about the commit metadata

It's time to talk a bit more about commit data-and-metadata.  We already mentioned that each commit has two parts:

- the data: a full snapshot of every file, frozen for all time;
- the metadata: information such as the name and email address of the author of the commit.

The snapshot is actually stored indirectly, through supporting objects.  This allows the files stored inside commits to be *de-duplicated*.  That way, since most commits mostly re-use files that are already in existing commits, the new commits don't need any space to *store* the files.  They just latch on to the already-existing files.  Since *no* part of *any* commit can *ever be changed*—not even by Git itself—it's quite safe to re-use pieces of old commits.

The metadata in a commit include things like when you made the commit and your log message: stuff that `git log` shows.  But for Git's own use, each commit stores a list of the raw hash IDs—the big ugly "true names"—of *previous* commits.  Most commits store exactly one entry in this list, which we call the *parent* commit.  We say that these hash IDs *point to* the parent.

In a non-empty repository with, say, three commits, we could draw them like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Here `C` is the third and latest commit (with some actual big ugly hash ID, but we're just calling it `C` for `commit`).  Inside commit `C`, in its metadata, we have the stuff that `git log` shows, plus the raw hash ID of earlier commit `B`, plus of course the data—the snapshot.  So by reading `C`, Git can *find* commit `B`.  This has a snapshot too.  By *comparing* the two snapshots, Git can show us what *changed* between `B` and `C`, and that's what `git log -p` does.

Having shown commit `C`, though, `git log` now uses the parent hash ID to step back one hop, to commit `B`.  `B`, like `C`, has data and metadata, and its metadata point to commit `A`.  So `git log` can use the snapshots in `A` and `B` to show us what *changed* in `B` ... and then `git log` can move on—or rather, back—to commit `A`.

Commit `A` is a bit special.  It has no parent.  It can't!  It was the first commit ever.  There was no *previous* commit.  So it just doesn't have any parents at all.  Git knows that this means that "what changed" in commit `A` is that every file in it was added from scratch, and `git log` knows that having shown commit `A`, it can finally stop going backwards: there's nowhere left to go.

The [flaw in the ointment](https://malaphors.com/2013/03/26/that-was-the-only-flaw-in-the-ointment/) here should be pretty obvious.  We had our `git log` work by "magically" knowing the hash ID of the last commit `C`.  But [there is no magic](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/440996-there-is-no-magic-there-is-only-knowledge-more-or).  Where did Git get commit `C`'s hash ID?

The answer is: *from a branch name*.  We have some *name*, like `master` or `main`, that holds commit `C`'s hash ID.  We say that this name *points to* the commit:

```
A <-B <-C   <--main
```

This name-and-value pair is stored in the *names* database, so Git just has to look that one up to get the hash ID for commit `C`.

#### Branch names find commits, and commits find commits

What this all means is that we use *branch names* to find the *last* commit of a branch, and then use the *commits* to find other, earlier commits.  That's what a branch name in Git is all about.  But there are several tricks:

- We can have more than one branch name.
- We can even have more than one branch name *for one commit*.

Let's draw the latter case:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main
```

(I've gotten deliberately lazy about drawing the arrows that lead backwards from one commit to the previous one here, mostly because the arrows in arrow-fonts don't always render very well on Stack Overflow, plus they are annoying to type in.)

We are going to be *using* commit `C`, no matter which *branch name* we pick, but we need to pick a branch name.  We need to *mark* that branch name as "the name we're using", too.  To do that, we'll attach the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase like this, to just one branch name:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

We're now using the name `main` to find commit `C`.

If we run `git switch develop` or `git checkout develop`, the picture changes slightly:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

We're still using commit `C`, but now we're using it *through the name `develop`.

Why does this matter?  Well, let's make a *new commit* now.  Without worrying about how we make new commits, we note that when we *do* make a new commit, Git does the following:

1. Git gathers up all the metadata it needs, such as the `user.name` and `user.email` settings to put in as the name and email address of the author of the new commit.
2. Git makes a snapshot of all of the files that should be frozen for all time in this new commit.
3. Git adds the *current commit* to the metadata, as the parent.  Git writes out the commit—the data-and-metadata—which computes a new unique hash ID.  That's some big ugly [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number, but we'll just call it commit `D` here.
4. Git writes `D`'s hash ID to the *current branch name*.

Since commit `D`'s *parent* is the *current commit* `C` in step 3, new commit `D` points backwards to existing commit `C`.  But step 4 updates the *name* `develop`, because that's the name `HEAD` is attached to:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

`HEAD` thus provides two things:

- it tells us which *branch name* is the *current branch name*, and
- by having Git read the *name*, it tells us which *commit* is the current *commit*.

Git can answer either question about `HEAD`: "what name does it hold" or "what hash ID does it represent".  Git just needs to ask itself the right *question*.

#### This gets us back to the anomalous empty repository case

In an empty repository, there are no commits, and therefore there are no branch names.  But if we "attach" `HEAD` to some *non-existent* name—in reality, in Git, that means writing the branch name to the file `.git/HEAD` (but with some complicating exceptions that we won't worry about here)—then running `git commit` can still do the four steps we showed:

- gather metadata;
- make snapshot;
- write metadata-and-snapshot to obtain initial commit; and
- write new commit's hash ID into branch name, thereby creating the branch name.

The last step—writing the hash ID—gives us:

```
A   <-- main (HEAD)
```

as long as the name stored "in" `HEAD` was `main`.  (The metadata for commit `A` omits any parent hash IDs because Git notices, when reading `HEAD`, that the name `main` does not exist: this makes `main` an *unborn branch*, as Git usually calls it, or an *orphan branch*, as Git sometimes, inconsistently, calls it.)

#### This explains some of your problems

If you run `git init` such that it *creates a new, empty* repository, there are no branch names yet.  But you're "on" some branch anyway.  The branch name you're "on" now determines the name of the branch you will *create* when you make the first commit.

The default name for a new, empty repository is `master`.  In very recent version of Git, you can use `-b main` as arguments *to* `git init` to change this to `main`.  You can also configure a setting, `init.defaultBranch`, to override the default `master`.

If you run `git init` such that it simply re-initializes an existing repository, you are on some branch now, and you're still on that branch.  The `init.defaultBranch` setting, if it exists and would be used, isn't used here.  You're just on whatever branch you're on: use `git status` or `git symbolic-ref HEAD` to find out what that is.

If you're in an *empty repository* right now, the branch you're "on" *does not exist*.  So you can't rename it, at least in older versions of Git: `git branch -m main` may not work.  (It might work, as this has been fixed up in new versions of Git: the branch rename code notices that you're on an unborn branch, and renames the unborn branch, which is simple enough to do internally, it's just that nobody *thought* to do it before.)

There are two procedures that *always* work, regardless of your Git vintage:

1. `git checkout --orphan main` will switch the name of the non-existent branch that you are on to `main`.  Your next commit will now create `main`.
2. You can create your first commit, which creates `master`, then rename `master` to `main` with `git branch -m main`.

These two procedures are of course only to be used in that empty-repository case.  In a *non*-empty repository, you're still on whatever branch you were on before you ran `git init` unnecessarily.  Your `git init` didn't *do* anything (so why did you bother?).

#### Using two repositories

You mention in step 2:

> 2. Created a repo in Github e.g. `my_repo`

When you *create a new repository* with GitHub's web interface (or, presumably, with their `gh` command line tool or CLI), you have two options:

- Create a totally empty repository.  This is like using `git init`.
- Create a repository with one initial commit that has some files in it: a README, a LICENSE, a COPYRIGHT, maybe even a `.gitignore`, and that sort of thing.  This is like using `git init` *and then making a commit*.

The difference between these is that in the *second* case, the GitHub repository now has *one commit in it*, which means *it can have branch names*.  In the first case, the GitHub repository has *no* commits, which means it *can't have any branch names*.

GitHub have, of course, changed their own default initial branch name to `main` instead of `master`.  This affects both the unborn-branch empty-repository case *and* the one-commit now-the-repository-isn't-empty-so-there's-a-branch case.

Unless you have some powerful need for *their* initial commit, I'd recommend you use the "create with no commits" option.  This makes your remaining tasks trivial.

There's another, more complex case, where your GitHub repository has a bunch of commits that you'd like to keep.  I'll touch on this one briefly for completeness.  Here, you will make use of the fact that Git repositories share *commits*, but not *branch names*.

Whenever we connect two Gits to each other with `git fetch` or `git push`, we're invoking the commit-sharing stuff.  But there are two important differences between fetch and push here:

- `git fetch` means *get me stuff from them*.  That is, I have my Git software, working on my repository ("my Git" collectively) call up their Git software and connect to their repository ("their Git").  Then my Git has their Git list out all their branch and tag names and the corresponding commit or other hash IDs.  My Git then checks: for each hash ID, do I have that object?  If not, my Git *gets* their objects from *their* Git, collecting *all the commits they have that I don't* in the process.

  So now I share all their commits.  (I might have some of my own that they don't, though.)  Now that I have all their commits, my Git can set *remote-tracking names* in my repository, to remember their *branch* names.  My Git will create or update my `origin/main` and `origin/develop` to remember the hash IDs they have stored in their `main` and their `develop`.

  The end result of this is that after the fetch, I have all their *commits*, but none of my *branches* have been touched.  My branch names are *mine*, not theirs.  If I have a `main` and a `fred`, their `main` doesn't affect my `main`, and if they have a `fred` it doesn't affect mine either.  If they have a `barney` or `flintstone` and I don't, I still don't have that branch.  I share their *commits*, not their *branches*.
- The `git push` command *sends* from my Git to their Git.  I pick something—usually a branch name, but what I really need here is a commit hash ID—in *my* repository.  I have my Git call up their Git and ask them if they have that hash ID.  If not, my Git sends over that commit, and any previous commits that might be required that they don't already have, until they have all the commits *leading up to* that last commit that I just sent them too.  (That way their `git log` can find all the commits, for instance.)

  But then, having sent them some of my commits—as many as I chose, but usually I choose by branch name so that I send them all the commits up to the last commit on some branch of mine—then something *different* happens.  I don't have them set some sort of remote-tracking name.  Instead, I ask them if they would please set one of *their **branch** names* to remember that commit hash ID.

  They *can* refuse to do this!  It's their choice as to whether they will let me set one of their branch names.  But if they allow it, I've just created or updated a branch name in *their* Git.  I don't have to use the same name on both sides.  I don't even have to use a *name* on *my* side at all:

  ```
  git push origin mybranch:free-the-ocean
  ```

  for instance, or:

  ```
  git push a123456:refs/heads/newbranch
  ```

  if `a123456` is a valid shortened hash ID for a commit in my repository.

So we share *commits*.  We *do not* share *branch names*, except to the extent that if I say `git push origin mybranch`, I mean `git push origin mybranch:mybranch`: I'm going to ask them to use the same branch name I'm using.  It's still *their* branch name, though.  It's not mine to control: I can only ask them to create or update theirs.

(GitHub in particular have "protected branches", which won't let people update them with `git push`.  Of course, if I own the GitHub repository, I can use the GitHub web administration pages to de-protect the name and push to it, and then re-protect it.  But you can see from this complicated process that I still wind up having to *ask permission*.  It's just that I'm asking *myself* for permission.)

#### So what's this about `origin/HEAD` anyway?

I mentioned:

```
git remote set-head origin --auto
```

up in the TL;DR section.  What this does is:

- call up their Git (via the name `origin`);
- ask them which of *their* branch names *their* `HEAD` is attached to; and
- create or update my `origin/HEAD` name—its full name is `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`—so that it is a symbolic ref to the remote-tracking name in my repository that corresponds to the same branch name in their repository.

Whew, that's a mouthful—or head-full—of concepts.  Let's take it apart a bit:

- their *branch* names, `main` and `develop` for instance
- are reflected in my *remote-tracking names* `origin/main` and `origin/develop`
- which my Git maintains when I run `git fetch` and `git push`.

That is, I run `git fetch origin`: my Git connects to their Git and gets from them a list of all their branch names and the commit hash IDs that go with those names.  My Git makes sure I share all those commits, too.  Now that I have all their *commits*, I can create or update remote-tracking names for each of their *branch names*.  My Git will do this automatically for me.

If their `HEAD` holds one of their branch names—and it does—then my `origin/HEAD` could hold one of my remote-tracking names.  The `git fetch` command *does not maintain this automatically*.<sup>3</sup>  Running `git remote set-head` lets you have your Git update it; see [the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for details.

The name stored *in* their `HEAD` is the name their Git will recommend at `git clone` time.  That is, when you run:

```
git clone <url>
```

your `git clone` operation will:

1. create an empty directory and do all its work there;
2. use `git init` to create a new, empty repository;
3. use `git remote add origin url` to create `origin`;
4. insert any necessary `git config` operations here;
5. run `git fetch`;
6. run `git checkout -b somebranch --track origin/somebranch`.

The branch name *in* step 6 that your Git *creates*, based on your `origin/` name that's based on one of their branch names, is the name you supplied to the `-b` option to `git clone`.  If you *didn't* supply a `-b` option, your Git asks their Git which name they recommend.  They recommend whatever name is in their `HEAD`.  So that's what their `HEAD` is really for: to act as a default recommendation to `git clone` operations.

Note that there's no Git protocol for setting `HEAD` in someone else's repository.  GitHub offer a configuration page where you can set your own repositories' `HEAD`s.  (At least one cloud provider—Google—seem to have failed to set up such a page, which leaves their `HEAD`s set to `master` even if they have a `main` instead.)

---

<sup>3</sup>I don't really know why.  It seems like it should.  It doesn't: you need to run `git remote` instead.  But Git explicitly lets you set `origin/HEAD` to any of your own remote-tracking names, regardless of which one *they* have *theirs* set to.  This is theoretically useful—see [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) and note step 6 of the name-resolving protocol—but I've never found it useful myself.

---

#### Stale remote-tracking names

Note that `git fetch` *does not clean up automatically:* if they *had* a `rumplestiltskin` branch yesterday, and your Git made `origin/rumplestiltskin` to match, and today their `rumplestiltskin` is gone, your left-over `origin/rumplestiltskin` sits there gathering dust.  You can run `git fetch --prune` or `git remote prune origin` to fix these up, or you can set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your configuration to make `git fetch` act like `git fetch --prune` by default.